# How to assign one JSON key to all output dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

I am working with Pyodbc to iterate through a table to return records as a JSON and send to a server for validation.  I am able to iterate and return the rows, however, the server is expecting the JSON to be in the format below.  How do I iterate through my results and append the  `{"MetaData": {}, "SRData":` keys to  each iterated result/output?  My code is below.
Desired Output:

```
{
    "MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {
        "SRNumber": "1-3580671"
    }
}, 
{
    "MetaData": {}, 
    "SRData": {
        "SRNumber": "1-3580156"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import requests

    connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=ServiceRequest; UID=SA;PWD=pwd'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""SELECT SRNumber FROM ContainerFC""")

    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

    results = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

    output = {"MetaData": {}, "SRData": results}


    print(json.dumps(output, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

    objects_file = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JSONOutput.txt'
    f = open(objects_file,'w')

    url = "url"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}
    r = requests.post(url, data= json.dumps(output), headers=headers,  verify=False)

    print >> f

    print 'It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.'


    conn.close()
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "MetaData": {},
    "SRData": [
        {
            "SRNumber": "1-3140751"
        },
        {
            "SRNumber": "1-5574551"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```python
import json
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDb_SQLEXPRESS")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = """
SELECT '1-3580671' AS SRNumber, 'foo' AS thing
UNION ALL
SELECT '1-3580156' AS SRNumber, 'bar' AS thing
"""
cursor.execute(sql)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    result = dict(zip(columns, row))
    results.append({"MetaData": {}, "SRData": result})

cnxn.close()

print(json.dumps(results, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

returning

```
[
    {
        "MetaData": {},
        "SRData": {
            "SRNumber": "1-3580671",
            "thing": "foo"
        }
    },
    {
        "MetaData": {},
        "SRData": {
            "SRNumber": "1-3580156",
            "thing": "bar"
        }
    }
]
```